# Jquery, xml, ajax filter search

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm stuck! I got an XML which look like this:

```
<ButikerOmbud>
    <ButikOmbud>
        <Typ>Butik</Typ>
        <Nr>1518</Nr>
        <Namn/>
        <Address1>Kungsgatan 34 C</Address1>
        <Address2/>
        <Address3>S-441 31</Address3>
        <Address4>ALINGSÅS</Address4>
        <Address5>Västra Götalands län</Address5>
        <Telefon>0322/101 61</Telefon>
        <ButiksTyp>Självbetjäning</ButiksTyp>
        <Tjanster>Dryckesprovning</Tjanster>
        <SokOrd>VÄSTERGÖTLAND;STORKEN,KRISTINEKYRKA</SokOrd>
        <Oppettider>...</Oppettider>
        <RT90x>6427551</RT90x>
        <RT90y>1306408</RT90y>
    </ButikOmbud>
    <ButikOmbud>
        <Typ>Butik</Typ>
        <Nr>0704</Nr>
        <Namn/>
        <Address1>Storgatan 14</Address1>
        <Address2/>
        <Address3>S-342 30</Address3>
        <Address4>ALVESTA</Address4>
        <Address5>Kronobergs län</Address5>
        <Telefon>0472/124 01</Telefon>
        <ButiksTyp>Självbetjäning</ButiksTyp>
        <Tjanster/>
        <SokOrd>
SMÅLAND;KRONOBERG;ALVESTA JÄRNVÄGSSTATION;ALVESTA KOMMUNHUS
        </SokOrd>
        <Oppettider>...</Oppettider>
        <RT90x>6308791</RT90x>
        <RT90y>1423876</RT90y>
    </ButikOmbud>
</ButikerOmbud>
```

I want to be able to search for , i.e "Gotlands län" and I want to return every `<Address1>`, `<Address4>`, and `<Telefon>` values, or all data of that node, but those three are the most important ones as for now.

Ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "systembolaget.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function (xml) {
                        var result = $(xml).find("ButikOmbud").filter(function() {
                          return $(this).find("Address5").text().indexOf('Gotlands län') === 0;
                        }).each(function() {
                            alert("THIS: "+this);                       
                        });
                        alert("RESULT: "+result);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Ett fel inträffade vid inläsandet av XML-filen");
                    }
                });
```

I receive the expected number of objects, but I have no clue on how to read data from those objects (alert("THIS: "+this) alers 3 times, and the xml contains 'Gotlands län' 3 times).

Comment: I didn't quite catch the problem. Wouldn't replacing `alert("THIS: " + this);` with `var addr1 = $(this).find("Address1").text(); var tel = $(this).find("Telefon").text();` and so on do the trick?

Comment: Youre right Shakurov! Stressed out and brain malfunction is not optimal when coding :-D